# ¿Cómo insertar el valor de una variable en la BD en Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

En mi **controlador** tengo una función de nombre **insertar**, tengo una **variable con un valor definido**, lo que yo quiero hacer es **insertar esa variable en la BD** pero me marca error les pongo lo que implementé y espero pueda aconsejarme.

```
      //Esta función de Insertar en la BD
      public function insertar(){   
      $ruta ='informacion local';//esta variable es la que quiero insertar
      $datos = array(
            'nombre_tabla'=>$this->input->post($ruta),
            'cambio_realizado' => $this->input->post('sistema_operativo',true),
            'id_usuario' => $this->input->post('id',true)
        );

        $this->modelo_principal->insertar($datos);
        }
```

En mi model pongo lo siguiente:

*Nota: mi tabla se llama **ruta** y le inserto lo que hay en la variable **$datos***

```
    public function insertar ($datos){
        $this->db->insert('ruta',$datos);
    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué error te genera?

Comment: Se envia la variable ruta pero al insertarse en la BD  me dice que llego NULL

Comment: Error Number: 1048

Column 'nombre_tabla' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `insertar` (`nombre_tabla`, `cambio_realizado`, `id_usuario`) VALUES (NULL, 'prueba', '1')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te está diciendo que no existe esto:

```
$this->input->post($ruta);
```

Que viene a ser lo mismo que esto:

```
$this->input->post('informacion local');
```

¿Puede qué tu quieras hacer esto?

```
 public function insertar(){   
     $ruta ='informacion local';//esta variable es la que quiero insertar
     $datos = array(
        'nombre_tabla'=>$ruta,
        'cambio_realizado' => $this->input->post('sistema_operativo',true),
        'id_usuario' => $this->input->post('id',true)
    );

    $this->modelo_principal->insertar($datos);
}
```

Comment: si efectivamente muchas gracias!!